# I want to solve Project Euler #1 more efficiently by using arithmetic progression formula, but my algorithm returns answers that are just slightly off

Tags: java, algorithm

This is the first, inefficient method I wrote:

```
public int sumOfMultiplesOf3or5Under1000() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Here is my attempt at coding a more efficient solution using the arithemtic progression formula:

```
public int usingAP() {
    return sumOfAP(3,3,333) + sumOfAP(5,5,199) - sumOfAP(15,15,66); 
}

public int sumOfAP(int firstTerm, int commonDifference, int numberOfTerms){
    int sum = (numberOfTerms / 2) * (2 * firstTerm + (numberOfTerms - 
               1) * commonDifference);
    return sum;
}
```

When I call sumOfMultiplesOf3or5Under1000() I get the correct answer:

233168

When I call usingAP() I get an answer that's off by just 1,001:

232167

Comment: Why do you consider the first method inefficient?  It only takes a couple seconds to calculate the sum up to 1 billion.

Comment: @JacobG. Maybe he wants to change `int` to `long` and do the calculation for 1000000000000000000, then with the first method it takes about 30 years, but with the second still about the same time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you consider your first method to be inefficient for the reason that I stated in the comment above.  Nevertheless, it seems you fell victim to rounding errors in your `sumOfAP` method.  You were close, but you just need some way to store the temporary variables as `double` instead of `int` so you can retain the precision.  I was able to fix it by dividing and multiplying by `2D` instead of `2`:

```
public static int sumOfAP(int firstTerm, int commonDifference, int numberOfTerms){
    return (int) ((numberOfTerms / 2D) * (2D * firstTerm + (numberOfTerms - 1) * commonDifference));
}
```

You can run the following and verify that they're equivalent:

```
System.out.println(usingAP());
System.out.println(sumOfMultiplesOf3or5Under1000());
```

Output:

```
233168
233168
```

Comment: Thank you so much!